# Counter for mask elements in a TYPO3 column

Tags: typo3, mask, typoscript, fluid, typo3-10.x

In a TYPO3 mask element, I need to know the position of the item in the current column. Like any iterator you would use in a template, but on the level of the column.

I know that with the syntax `{cObject}.renderObj.{maskElement}.settings.xyz` I can pass in values into the mask element's fluid template. But apparently, TypoScript that goes to `settings` is not rendered, is that correct?

I tried this:

```
pageteasers < styles.content.get
pageteasers.select.where = colPos=2
pageteasers {
    renderObj.mask_teaser.settings {
        set_number = LOAD_REGISTER
        set_number {
            counter2.cObject = TEXT
            counter2.cObject.data = register:counter2
            counter2.cObject.wrap = |+1
            counter2.prioriCalc = intval
        }
        get_number = TEXT
        get_number = register:counter2
    }
}
```

Or simpler

```
pageteasers < styles.content.get
pageteasers.select.where = colPos=2
pageteasers {
    renderObj.mask_teaser.settings {
        elementId = {cObj:parentRecordNumber}
    }
}
```

This will output the string `{cObj:parentRecordNumber}`.

My questions are:

- Is there another "road" into the mask element from TS than `settings` where maybe the objects are rendered?
- How do I number the elements in my column anyway...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for variables instead of settings, since those are rendered as cObjects and therefor offer you the fully blown stdWrap tool box.

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/Index.html#variables

```
pageteasers < styles.content.get
pageteasers.select.where = colPos=2
pageteasers {
    renderObj.mask_teaser {
        variables {
            // count up elements
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844215/counter-for-mask-elements-in-a-typo3-column // <- Self-reference!
            elementCounter = TEXT
            elementCounter.value = {cObj:parentRecordNumber}
            elementCounter.insertData = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks & Good to know that „settings“ is not rendered! — But I‘m not sure the mask element will accept the variables, as I tried that first and it wouldn‘t see them. 

What I did was the same code as above, but with „variables“ instead of „settings“. Or does that require a different syntax?

Comment: Yeah, it’s that SO forces you to wait 7hours to accept your own answer. If you want you can add the working code to your answer and then I can accept that one with the complete result!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this works also for non-mask items, right? But how? I have a news plugin I need to feed with the same variables in the same column. But I can't figure out how to address it properly so it receives the variables... is this also via `renderObj.{element}`? Can you help me what to add there @jo-hasenau?

Comment: How about plugin.tx_news?

Comment: Do you mean `pageteasers.renderObj.plugin.tx_news.variables.myVar = 1`? That doesn't seem to work

Comment: Sure! It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403392/