# Pass a variable to a content object containing a tx_news plugin

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, tx-news, typo3-10.x

This is very similar to my question [Counter for mask elements in a TYPO3 column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67844215/counter-for-mask-elements-in-a-typo3-column/67847937)

I need to pass a variable (in my case, the value of `cObj:parentRecordNumber` which is the counter for the current item in it's column) to the template.

In the main page template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.content.pageteasers" />
```

In typoscript:

```
lib.content {
    pageteasers < styles.content.get
    pageteasers {
        select {
            where = colPos=2
            max = 8
        }
        // this passes the variable elementCounter to the fluid template of the rendered mask content element:
        renderObj.mask_teaser {
            variables {
                elementCounter = TEXT
                elementCounter.value = {cObj:parentRecordNumber}
                elementCounter.insertData = 1
            }
        }
        // this should pass the same value to a rendered tx_news plugin: 
        variables {
                elementCounter = TEXT
                elementCounter.value = {cObj:parentRecordNumber}
                elementCounter.insertData = 1
        }
        // it doesn't. what about these trial & error:
        renderObj.list < .variables
        renderObj.plugin.tx_news < .variables
        renderObj.list.20.news_pi1 < .variables
        renderObj.news_pi1 < .variables
        // none of these seem to work either 
    }
 }
```

And then in the rendered CE template (`News/List.html`)

```
<f:debug title="" inline="1">{_all}</f:debug>
```

I don't manage to see the above variable in here. What is the correct way to pass the variable from TS to the news fluid template?

---

PS Another try was using the Good Old Register

```
pageteasers < styles.content.get
pageteasers {
    select {
        where = colPos=2
        max = 8
    }
    append = LOAD_REGISTER
    append {
      elementCounter = TEXT
      elementCounter.value = {cObj:parentRecordNumber}
      elementCounter.insertData = 1
   }
}
```

And in the template:

```
{v:variable.register.get(name: 'elementCounter')}
```

but that is `NULL`

Comment: Your snippet works for CE of cType "FLUIDTEMPLATE". Plugins are of type "USER/USER_INT" and do (normally) *not* have the property "variables".

Comment: Is there a workaround to "communicate" with the Plugin?

Comment: But the Plugin uses a FLUIDTEMPLATE in the end, doesn't it? Can't I get through to it somehow?

Comment: The Plugin uses a Fluid-Template, yes. But it does not pass through the variables. Don't mix up a Fluid-Template (=> HTML) and an FLUIDTEMPLATE-cObject (=> TypoScript).
In your case (Displaying the value of a cObject), there's no need to pass it via variables into the template. The cObject-Viewhelper should solve this: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/10.4/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/CObject.html

Comment: Thanks Julian. I'm not sure how to interpret your solution proposal though. Can you make an example as answer?  `cObj:parentRecordNumber` is not available in the content object by default.

Comment: PS tx_news has a `contentObjectData` property which displays already. But this does not contain the desired information

Comment: In your code snippets, you are including always `{cObj:parentRecordNumber}`. Instead of including this in TypoScript, you could use `<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="parentRecordNumber" />` directly in the Fluid template.
Where are you taking parentRecordNumber from? Isn't it a global TS-Object?

Comment: No, it's a property (?) of GetText https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/DataTypes/Properties/GetText.html#cobj

Comment: Oh, didn't know that till now :-o  ( https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/DataTypes/Properties/GetText.html#cobj )
There are always things/features, you don't know even after years of working with TYPO3... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your try via register could work. But you have to care, where you are doing what...

### Registers

[`LOAD_REGISTER`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/LoadRegister/Index.html) is of type *string/stdWrap* and ***not*** a *cObject* per definition. If you wanna use content based on a *cObject*, you can declare this via the *stdWrap*-property (as shown in the examples):

```
1 = LOAD_REGISTER
1.param.cObject = TEXT
1.param.cObject.stdWrap.data = GP:the_id
```

So, in your case it should like:

```
elementCounter.cObject = TEXT
elementCounter.cObject.data = cObj:parentRecordNumber
```

### Appending at the right place

You are trying to use *append* directly as a property of `pageteasers` (which is a copy of `styles.content.get` which is of type [`CONTENT`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/LoadRegister/Index.html).

`CONTENT` does not have an *append*-property. In addition, you would put the register in front of the entire content, not the individual content elements.
=> It's needed as part of the *renderObj*, so it's rendered per CE.

The *renderObj* of `CONTENT` is of type [`CASE`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/ContentObjects/Content/Index.html), which also has no *stdWrap*-properties directly. But it has a property `stdWrap` with *stdWrap*-properties...

### Conclusion

So, you can end up with this snippet:

```
lib.content {
  pageteasers {   
    renderObj {
      stdWrap {
        append = LOAD_REGISTER
        append {
          elementCounter.cObject = TEXT
          elementCounter.cObject.data = cObj:parentRecordNumber
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Julian, sorry for not reacting before! I didn't see your answer until now.

Comment: I see the question is already getting downvotes :-) No luck with your conclusion either yet, though, sorry!